# Issues with graph generated by momepy from GeoPandas Data Frame

Tags: python, geopandas, networkx, osmnx

I'm trying to create a graph from a GeoPandas Data Frame, but am having an issue where some roads are being excluded, and others are not joined up correctly. As well as that, I'm getting these large circles in the graph. You can see in the figure below, where the data frame is plotted directly in orange, and the generated graph is plotted on top in black.

The code to reproduce this figure is below.

What can I do to make the generated graph fit the road layout better, and what are these large circles and how do I remove them?

I assume the issue is with momepy, is there a better alternative that I could use?

[image: Figure 1]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import momepy
import networkx as nx

place_name = 'Trumpington Ward, UK'

tags = {'highway': ['motorway', 'trunk', 'primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'unclassified', 'residential', 'motorway_link', 'trunk_link', 'primary_link', 'secondary_link', 'tertiary_link', 'living_street', 'service', 'pedestrian']}
roads = ox.geometries_from_place(place_name, tags).to_crs(epsg=3857)
roads = roads.drop(roads[roads['area'] == 'yes'].index)

graph = momepy.gdf_to_nx(roads, approach='primal')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
roads.plot(color='#e32e00', ax=ax, zorder=-1)
nx.draw(graph, {n:[n[0], n[1]] for n in graph.nodes}, ax=ax, node_size=0)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find out why momepy wasn't producing a graph that offered full coverage of the road network in the gdf. However, I did find out that the circles are actually representing self-loops. I do not know why these were created, but they can easily be removed, as networkx has a method to get all the self-loops in a graph.

But, there is an alternative. I didn't know at the time, but osmnx has a `graph_from_place`, so as long as you don't need to convert an existing gdf to a graph, this method is perfect. Here you can see it used to achieve what was attempted in the original question:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox

place = 'Trumpington Ward, UK'
filter = '["highway"~"motorway|trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|unclassified|residential|motorway_link|trunk_link|primary_link|secondary_link|tertiary_link|living_street|service|pedestrian"]'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type=None, truncate_by_edge=True, custom_filter=filter)


tags = {'highway': ['motorway', 'trunk', 'primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'unclassified', 'residential', 'motorway_link', 'trunk_link', 'primary_link', 'secondary_link', 'tertiary_link', 'living_street', 'service', 'pedestrian']}
roads = ox.geometries_from_place(place, tags)#.to_crs(epsg=3857)
roads = roads.drop(roads[roads['area'] == 'yes'].index)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
roads.plot(color='#e32e00', ax=ax, zorder=-1)
ox.plot_graph(G, ax, node_size=0)
plt.show()
```

Which produces this image:

[image: Trumpington Ward]

As you can see, this is a much better result. You can also pass `network_type='drive'` instead of a custom filter, in order to get the drivable roads.